# IOS nsmutable array index no 2 insert one more value or dictionary with old value

Tags: ios, insert, nsmutablearray

i have one mutable array with some value , In this array i have add one dictionary on index no 3 with old value , i mean to say i have add one more value on index no 3 Here is my data 
**This is my mutable array **

```
(        {
        Amount = 40;
        DisplayMessage = "Select at least 1 item and a maximum of 1";
        DisplayOrder = 1;
        IsMandatory = 1;
        IsQtyEditable = 0;

    },
        {
        Amount = 30;
        DisplayMessage = "Select at least 1 item and a maximum of 1";
        DisplayOrder = 1;
        IsMandatory = 1;
        IsQtyEditable = 0;

    },
        {
        Amount = 10;
        DisplayMessage = "Select at least 1 item and a maximum of 1";
        DisplayOrder = 1;
        IsMandatory = 1;
        IsQtyEditable = 0;

    }
)
```

on index no 3 i have add dictionary **mytxt = 1;**
Like this (in last line i have add mytxt = 1; on index no 3 )

```
{
            Amount = 10;
            DisplayMessage = "Select at least 1 item and a maximum of 1";
            DisplayOrder = 1;
            IsMandatory = 1;
            IsQtyEditable = 0;
            mytxt = 1;
        }
```

Here is my code i try this but is return a error

```
for (int i =0; i< ArrayGetParent.count; i++) {

                        if(i == 3 )
                        {
                            NSMutableDictionary *dictArray=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                            [dictArray setValue:@"1" forKey:@"mytxt"];
                            NSLog(@"%@",dictArray);
                            [nishantArray insertObject:dictArray atIndex:i];
                        }
                    }
```

this is my error 
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'**

Please help me . please share your valuable knowledge .

Comment: your array is not a mutable, correct this , surly works

Answer (score 0):

`nishantArray` is not mutable, check where you define it and change it

Comment: in nsmutable array i m using addObject its not return error but i am using  [[ArrayGetParent objectAtIndex:i] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"mytxt"]; its return immutable object error , and i am sure this is nsmutableArray

Answer (score 0):

Define array as :

```
NSMutableArray *ArrayGetParent = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

**NOTE**  : You have only three object according to array and in your for loop you take `i = 3` it is not possible.

Solution :

```
for (int i =0; i< ArrayGetParent.count; i++) {

        if(i == 2)
        {
            [[ArrayGetParent objectAtIndex:i] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"mytxt"];

        }
    }
```

Adding data only last dictionary **OUTPUT**

[image]